# jhipster 5.4.2 skipping user management error

Tags: jhipster

Upon installing jhipster 5.4.2 (skipping user management):

jhipster --skip-user-management

I get the following error:

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                          22:02:12

This relative module was not found:

- ./user-management in ./src/main/webapp/app/shared/reducers/index.ts
  ✖ ｢wdm｣:    971 modules

ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/shared/reducers/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './user-management' in '/Users/spasco/code/web/polarisnousers/src/main/webapp/app/shared/reducers'
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: A bug, please report it on github

Comment: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8549